# autoincrement id which will use the lowest number available c++

Tags: c++, auto-increment

So I am creating a database, when adding items the user can provide the id number by themselves or just let the program create one for them. I want the ID to be the lowest number currently available. So lets say on record 0 the user adds and item and gives it an id 10. This means that the second record without specified ID should take 0. I also will assume that the user knows what he is doing so there is no need to check if the value is original.

This is what i have until now, my input is in a form of string typed in specified format. I cut it down to smaller chunks and then the values that are supposed to be parameters e.g. add items (id,name,price), if the user wants the id to be done by the database the input is ($,name,price)

id,name,amount being parameters
items is a structure. My assumption is that the user will know what he is doing so for now I want to keep the things fairly primitive. Currently it will just make the current record number its ID. Unfortunately the user can use that ID too and therefore make my autoincrement id loose.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
            if (items[i].used == 0){
                if (parameter[0] != "$"){
                    items[i].id = atoi(parameter[0].c_str());

                }
                else
                {
                    items[i].id = i;

                }
                items[i].name = parameter[1];
                items[i].price = atoi(parameter[2].c_str());
                items[i].used = 1;
                break;

            }
        }
```

Comment: do not allow users to input IDs, they are not designed for that.

Comment: 1) Check if your autoincrement nextval exists. 2) If it does exist, increment it and check again.